# Data on "perfect use" vs "typical use" of contraceptives?

Tags: sex, contraception, data, condom

Different kinds of contraceptives have different yearly failure rates depending on whether the user of the contraceptive follows all the proper procedures for the contraceptive ("perfect use"), or uses the contraceptive as the typical person would ("typical use").

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods

As part of a research project, I need to know what percentage of actual people use condoms (as well as other contraceptives) in such a way so as to fall into the "typical use" category or "perfect use" category. Do such data exist? If so, where might I find it?